# Oracle SQL. Collect multiple rows into one without analytic functions, hierarchy and recursion

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a strange question. From this input:

```
ID
1
3
6
8
9
11
23
```

... I need to get this output:

```
ID    Res
1      1
3      1,3,1
6      1,3,6,3,1
8      1,3,6,8,6,3,1
9      1,3,6,8,9,8,6,3,1
11     1,3,6,8,9,11,9,8,6,3,1
```

The main problem is that I have a requirement to make a query without ***Model clause, analytic functions, regexps, CONNECT BY, recursive WITH, WM_CONCAT and LISTAGG***. These are business rules... I wonder if there is a way to do this. Maybe a function that may be used to collect some rows into one? Or a construction that I've forgot about. Any suggestion will be helpful.

P.S. PL/SQL is excluded too

Comment: *Business rules*? Why would *business* care about the way you solve the problem? Oh, yes - and a *function* that might be used is PL/SQL which is excluded in P.S.

Comment: Does it need to work with any other data besides what you have provided? If not just hard code the answer in a case statement. :)

Comment: It might be helpful to explain exactly why you have these "business rules".  What version of Oracle do you use?  When you say "PL/SQL" is excluded, do you mean PL/SQL objects, or all PL/SQL statements?  You could possibly do this with a PL/SQL WITH, in 12c.

Comment: "Business rules" applies to a business. Never mind the restrictions; what business would have a **problem** like this to solve in the first place? What is the **business** problem you are modeling? You won't make many friends here lying about your homework assignment. Or was it an interview question?

Comment: "Business rules" like you have an old version of Oracle? Or "Business rules" like the old DBA in the closet is afraid of useful functions?

Comment: Wow, sorry, I mean that I have to find a solution to that problem if it is possible. "Excluding PL/SQL" means excluding creation of functions and procedural code.

Comment: I have tried joining table 5 times with itself and formatting output. But it doesn't work on tables with more than 130 rows

Comment: That's like asking I want you to help me build a house but the business rules say  not to use anything like concrete, steel, water, wood, paints,wires.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what is the reason behind the restriction, we can understand better and decide a different approach. Right know you are telling us to write Moby Dick novel without using vowels. If you cant use a store procedure you will have to do that on the presentation layer.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you tried with the 5 joins along with its output for the example input?

Comment: *'it doesn't work on tables with more than 130 rows'*. Please post your code and describe how it doesn't work. Also, how many rows do you want it to work for? What's the largest value of `ID` you have? You are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to spend **their time** helping you; the least you can do is invest some of **your time** framing a decent question.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only way I've found to get the result with all the limitations you have; not so elegant, but...

It's based on the idea to build the concatenation with XML functions and then elaborate the resulting strings to get the result.

With this table:

```
create table tab(ID) as (
    select 1  from dual union all
    select 3  from dual union all
    select 6  from dual union all
    select 8  from dual union all
    select 9  from dual union all
    select 11 from dual union all
    select 23 from dual
)
```

this

```
select id,
       rtrim(
             replace( replace(
                              extract(
                                       xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml
                                             (
                                              'select id from (select 1 pos, id from tab where id <=' || id ||
                                              ' union all select 2, id from tab where id < ' || id || 
                                              ') order by pos, case when pos = 1 then id else -id end')
                                             )
                                       ,'/ROWSET/ROW/ID'
                                     )
                              , '<ID>', '')
                        , '</ID>', ','
                      )
               , ','
              ) as result
from tab t1;
```

gives:

```
        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 1
         3 1,3,1
         6 1,3,6,3,1
         8 1,3,6,8,6,3,1
         9 1,3,6,8,9,8,6,3,1
        11 1,3,6,8,9,11,9,8,6,3,1
        23 1,3,6,8,9,11,23,11,9,8,6,3,1
```

How it works: the inner query gives, for a given `ID`, the list of `ID`s in the needed order, but as rows and not concatenated values; for example, for `ID = 6`, we have

```
select id
from (
        select 1 pos, id
        from tab
        where id <= 6
        union all
        select 2, id
        from tab
        where id < 6 
) order by pos,
case when pos = 1 then id else -id end
```

that gives :

```
        ID
----------
         1
         3
         6
         3
         1
```

The XML part is used to transform a list of values for every `ID`, in a single value (`xmltype`) and the `replace`/`trim` part is used to extract data from the XML.

For example, the XML for `ID=6`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <ID>3</ID>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <ID>6</ID>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <ID>3</ID>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

However, I consider this more an exercise than a piece of code that I would like to see in a real system.

Comment: This works well enough. I think the solution is obscure enough that whoever the OP shows it to will know they cribbed it from StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun. My example of using a case statement:

```
create table test (ID number);

insert into test values(1);
insert into test values(3);
insert into test values(6);
insert into test values(8);
insert into test values(9);
insert into test values(11);
insert into test values(23);

commit;

select id,
case id
when 1 then '1'
when 3 then '1,3,1'
when 6 then '1,3,6,3,1'
when 8 then '1,3,6,8,6,3,1'
when 9 then '1,3,6,8,9,8,6,3,1'
when 11 then '1,3,6,8,9,11,9,8,6,3,1'
end as "Res"
from test
where id <> 23
order by id;
```

Outputs:

```
        ID Res
---------- ----------------------
         1 1
         3 1,3,1
         6 1,3,6,3,1
         8 1,3,6,8,6,3,1
         9 1,3,6,8,9,8,6,3,1
        11 1,3,6,8,9,11,9,8,6,3,1
```

At least it doesn't use anything exotic which seems to be the question. I guess this is for some class or test?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package with a function, see below sample,

```
create table tab_test(ID) as (
    select 1  from dual union all
    select 3  from dual union all
    select 6  from dual union all
    select 8  from dual union all
    select 9  from dual union all
    select 11 from dual
);


create or replace package pkg_test
as
    v_id NUMBER;
    v_ids VARCHAR2(200);
    FUNCTION get_ids (p_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/

create or replace package body pkg_test
as
    FUNCTION get_ids (p_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
    is
        v_rev_text VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
        IF v_ids IS NULL THEN
           v_ids := p_id;
           RETURN v_ids;
        ELSE
           v_ids := v_ids||', '||p_id;
        END IF;
        SELECT substr(reverse(v_ids), length(p_id) + 1)
          into v_rev_text
          from dual;
        RETURN v_ids||', '||trim(',' from trim(v_rev_text));
    END;
END;
/

--Always run this before the select statement,

begin
   pkg_test.v_ids := null;
end;
/

select pkg_test.get_ids(id)
  from tab_test;
```

Output:

```
Result
-----------------------
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1, 3, 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1, 3, 6, 3 ,1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1, 3, 6, 8, 6 ,3 ,1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 8 ,6 ,3 ,1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11, 9 ,8 ,6 ,3 ,1
```

6 rows selected

Comment: The OP said no PLSQL